# Mongoose shows .find() locally but not when put to remote server "MongoLab"

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN stack course and have come to a roadblock.
I was hoping someone out there may be able to direct me as to what may be wrong in my code.

I have a MongoDB locally(and on MongoLab remotely) with a collection 'messages' that contains { message : 'some text' }. 
When I do a db.messages.find() on both they are essentially identical.However, only works on the local mongod server.

The code most certainly is seeing the collection as I accidentally typed in message(instead of messages) for the collection initially and it was throwing an error. When I corrected that no errors were thrown but I do not get the find displayed anymore when I pull the page.

Here is the code, any ideas what may be preventing the remote version of messages from displaying the find() results?

```
   var express = require('express'),
    stylus = require('stylus'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

function compile(str, path){
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path)
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(stylus.middleware(
    {
        src: __dirname + '/public',
        compile: compile
    }
));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/multivision');
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://login:password:53139/mvision');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://login:password@kahana.mongohq.com:10068/multivision');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, ' connection error..'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('multivision db opened');
});

var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({message: String});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var mongoMessage;
Message.find().exec(function(err, messageDoc){
    mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
});

app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});

app.get('*', function(req,res){
    res.render('index', {
        mongoMessage: mongoMessage
    });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);
```

The only thing i've noticed that seems out of the ordinary from what I am used to and I did not see on the video was when I insert into the collection I get the message; Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatibility mode.   However, find from the console shows message.

```
set-53864e952712560278002d23:PRIMARY> show collections
messages
system.indexes
system.users
set-53864e952712560278002d23:PRIMARY> db.messages.insert({message: "hello mongo3
"})
Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatability mode
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
set-53864e952712560278002d23:PRIMARY> db.messages.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53b586a399abc5fe42a2e96e"), "message" : "hello mongo3" }
```